# how to use react-slick slider for multiple images in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

[I dont want like that output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCCZ7.png) how to do that. I am developing but it is not adjusted
const settings = {
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
    }; 
`<div >
              <Slider {...settings} >
                <div style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  marginTop:'10px',
                  marginBottom: '10px',
                  marginLeft: '15%',
                  }}>
                  <div><img  width= '200px' height= '200px'   src='/assets/images/oem/main/apple-iphone-5s-small.png'/></div>
                  <div><img width= '200px' height= '200px' src='/assets/images/oem/main/Apple.png' /></div>
                  <div><img width= '200px' height= '200px' src='/assets/images/oem/main/apple-iphone-5s-big.png' /></div>
                  <div><img width= '200px' height= '200px' src='/assets/images/oem/main/apple-iphone-5s-small.png' /></div>
                </div>`

Comment: Need some code.

Comment: const settings = {
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
    };

Comment: Please put the code to your slider in the question and state what you want it to do and what is is doing right now.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [Multiple Items Example](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/examples/MultipleItems.js) (visual [here](http://neostack.com/opensource/react-slick))?
If you want to have 3 images displayed at one time, you change the settings to:

```
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 3
```

Comment: I already put like that const settings = {
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
    };